# MySQL: BETWEEN - Different result in query

Tags: mysql, between

I have a strange behavior and I would be glad if anyone could explain this, please? and today is the 22nd May 2016 (for future readers).

```
SELECT `Opened`,
  `Milestone_Status`,
  Year(`Opened`), 
  Month(`Opened`), 
  Count(*) As Total_Rows 
FROM Cases 
WHERE `Opened` BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) 
GROUP BY Year(`Opened`), Month(`Opened`), `Milestone_Status`;
```

The result is following:

```
+------------+------------------+----------------+-----------------+------------+
| Opened     | Milestone_Status | Year(`Opened`) | Month(`Opened`) | Total_Rows |
+------------+------------------+----------------+-----------------+------------+
| 2016-12-07 | Compliant        |           2016 |              12 |          2 |
| 2017-01-10 | Compliant        |           2017 |               1 |          6 |
| 2017-02-23 | Closed Violation |           2017 |               2 |          1 |
| 2017-02-27 | Compliant        |           2017 |               2 |          1 |
| 2017-03-01 | Closed Violation |           2017 |               3 |          1 |
| 2017-03-06 | Compliant        |           2017 |               3 |          2 |
+------------+------------------+----------------+-----------------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

So when I change one month difference from 2 to 3, it should show the lines till Month('Opened') 2, but ..

```
SELECT `Opened`,
  `Milestone_Status`,
  Year(`Opened`), 
  Month(`Opened`), 
  Count(*) As Total_Rows 
FROM Cases WHERE `Opened` BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) 
GROUP BY Year(`Opened`), Month(`Opened`), `Milestone_Status`;

result:
+------------+------------------+----------------+-----------------+------------+
| Opened     | Milestone_Status | Year(`Opened`) | Month(`Opened`) | Total_Rows |
+------------+------------------+----------------+-----------------+------------+
| 2016-12-07 | Compliant        |           2016 |              12 |          2 |
| 2017-01-10 | Compliant        |           2017 |               1 |          6 |
+------------+------------------+----------------+-----------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Any ideas, better ways, please?

Comment: well *2017 ????

Comment: CURRENT_DATE () - INTERVAL 6 MONTH ==  2016-11-22 and CURRENT_DATE () - INTERVAL 3 MONTH ==  2017-02-22, so everything is ok with your query :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So when I change one month difference from 2 to 3, it should show the lines till Month('Opened') 2, but ..

Because today is 22 so your result is true.

If you want to get Month('Opened') from 2, try it with month.

Edit: CURRENT_DATE with DATEADD()

Ex: 3 month: DATEADD(m, -3, GETDATE()).

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

No, the output is correct. As

```
 CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
```

is

> 2017-02-22

So you query becomes :

```
SELECT `Opened`,`Milestone_Status`,YEAR(`Opened`), MONTH(`Opened`), 
COUNT(*) AS Total_Rows
FROM Cases WHERE `Opened`
BETWEEN (2016-11-22) AND (2017-02-22)
GROUP BY YEAR(`Opened`), MONTH(`Opened`), `Milestone_Status`;
```